# Get Offset of Pin mrker from the Boundary OSMdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

Currently I am working with the OSMdroid, and its working fine but i m having an issue.
When the Pins are at the Boundary of MBTIles i want to get the Offset of the Pin marker from the boundary and want to display it some other location.
How to achieve this [image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking how to find the pixel distance between a point on the map and the edge of the phone's screen.

You can get the coordinates of the screen by calling: `mMapView.getProjection().getScreenRect()`

And then you can get the coordinates of the point on the map by calling:
`mMapView.getProjection().toPixels()`

From there you can subtract x and y values to find out how far your point is from the edge of the screen.

Some additional notes - `toPixels()` will be called `toMapPixels()` in older osmdroid versions. Also you can "cache" the lat/long to pixel conversion for the point using `toProjectedPixels()` and `toPixelsFromProjected()` to save CPU cycles.